# IntelliJ include a directory contained in an excluded directory?

Tags: intellij-idea, protocol-buffers, project-structure, generated-code

Can IntelliJ include a source directory contained in an excluded directory?

I am using Google Protocol Buffers and am placing the generated class files in the `target/proto-generated` directory. I have already excluded the target directory, is there a way to mark `proto-generated` as a source directory **and** leave the `target` directory excluded?

- target <*excluded*>

  - classes
  - proto-generated <***include***>

Comment: See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6054 for the workaround.

Comment: can you share your build.gradle file ! thanks .

Comment: @issamux This was more than 3 years ago... I don't have access to that code anymore.

Comment: @MikeRylander , no problems... i ve solved my problem, and it wasn't related to this, so , thanks :)

Comment: I've same problem. Basically, generated model files of *.protoc are generated into target/proto-generated directory, so the intellisense of intelij is not working for those model classes. Is there anyway to work around with this? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks CrazyCoder for

*"See [youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6054](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6054) for the workaround."*